# How to call Oracle Function or Procedure using Hibernate (EntityManager) or JPA

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, sys-refcursor

I have an Oracle function which return sys-refcursor and when I call this function using Hibernate, I am getting the following exception.

```
Hibernate: { ? = call my_function(?) }
 org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1360)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1288)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:313)
```

How can I resolve this?

**Oracle function**

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION my_function(p_val IN varchar2)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  AS
    my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
    OPEN my_cursor FOR SELECT emp_name FROM employees
    WHERE lower(emp_name) like lower(p_val||'%');
    RETURN my_cursor;    
  END;
```

**My Entity class**

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery(name = "getFunc", query = 
"{ ? = call my_function(:empName) }", 
 resultClass = Employee.class, hints = 
 { @javax.persistence.QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true") })
 @Table(name = "EMPLOYEES")
```

**and in DAO**

```
    @Override
        public void findEmployees(QueryData data,
                String empName) {

        List query = (List) entityManager.createNamedQuery("getFunc")
                         .setParameter("empName", empName)
                         .getSingleResult();
                data.setResult(query);
}
```

Comment: A named query is not the same thing as a stored procedure.  I'm not sure you can do what you're proposing.

Comment: @duffymo So using Hibernate 4, what is the best way to call a database function?

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524841/call-stored-procedure-in-hibernate

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Oracle function or a stored procedure can be called using EntityManager in the following manner.

**For Oracle Function**

Create a function with sys_refcursor as return type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function
(p_val IN varchar2)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  AS
    my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
    OPEN my_cursor FOR SELECT emp_name FROM employees
    WHERE lower(emp_name) like lower(p_val||'%');
    RETURN my_cursor;    
  END;
```

In Entity class, define function as

```
@javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery(name = "getFunc", query = "{? =  call
my_function(:empName) }", resultClass = Employee.class, hints = {
@javax.persistence.QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true") })
```

**For Oracle Stored Procedure**

Create procedure with `sys_refcursor` as first OUT parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProcedure(p_cursor out sys_refcursor,
     p_val  in varchar2
)
 AS
BEGIN
     OPEN o_cursor FOR
          SELECT     emp_name 
             FROM     employees 
            WHERE     LOWER (emp_name) LIKE lower(p_val||'%');
```

In Entity class define procedure as

```
@javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery(name = "getProc", query = "{ call
my_procedure(?,:empName) }", resultClass = Employee.class, hints = {
@javax.persistence.QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true") })
```

and finally in DAO class, call function or procedure as

```
Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getFunc"); // if procedure then getProc 
query.setParameter("empName","smith"); 
query.getResultList();
```

Thanks

Comment: JPA 2.1 introduced much better support for stored procedures (e.g. more that one output parameter). See [JPA 2.1 Stored Procedures](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#JPA_2.1_StoredProcedureQuery) for further details

Comment: @Jacob Hey, I am getting **Invalid Column Index** exception when calling function. What is the reason?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher My reckoning would be to post a question with code snippet to analyse rather than a comment.

Comment: You are right! But then I have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54017772/mixed-parameter-strategies-use-just-one-of-named-positional-or-jpa-ordinal-st/54023121#54023121

Answer (score 5):

For your function,

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION my_function(p_val IN varchar2)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  AS
    my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
    OPEN my_cursor FOR SELECT emp_name FROM employees
    WHERE lower(emp_name) like lower(p_val||'%');
    RETURN my_cursor;    
  END;
```

You can define the following `NamedNativeQuery`:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "my_function",
    query = "{ ? = call my_function( ? ) }",
    callable = true,
    resultClass = String.class
)
```

And, you can call the query like this:

```
List<String> employeeNames = entityManager
    .createNamedQuery("my_function")
    .setParameter(1, 1L)
    .getResultList();
```

For a stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE my_procedure(p_val IN VARCHAR2, 
    my_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
) 
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN my_cursor FOR
    SELECT emp_name FROM employees
    WHERE lower(emp_name) like lower(p_val||'%');
END;
```

, you can use the following JPA 2.1 query:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
    .createStoredProcedureQuery("my_procedure")
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, 
         ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Class.class, 
         ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
    .setParameter(1, 1L);
 
query.execute();
 
List<Object[]> result = query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Procedure:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure(p_val IN VARCHAR2, 
  my_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) 
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN my_cursor FOR SELECT emp_name FROM employees 
      WHERE lower(emp_name) like lower(p_val||'%');
END;
```

**Alternative Solution: Call procedure with sys_refcursor as OUT parameter without defining @NamedNativeQuery**

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("myProcedure");
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    query.setParameter(2, "Umesh");
    List result = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Querying JPA Entities with JPQL and Native SQL: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing Oracle functions with Oracle stored procedures.

Functions can be invoked from a select statement - user defined functions like yours act the same way as the built-in functions, like min() and max(). They cannot be invoked by an external "call" like stored procedures can.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions231.htm#i1012049 for the definition of a function.

You probably will need to re-write your function as a stored procedure.

Comment: Yes you are right I could invoke a function using a select statement like `select my_function('smith') from dual`. Using Hibernate 4 EntityManager how can I call this function or select statement to get the desired results? Thanks

Comment: Based on your functionality, it looks like you need to make it stored procedure instead of a function.

Comment: [Here](http://timezra.blogspot.in/2008/10/spring-hibernate-and-oracle-stored.html) a pl/sql function is being called, but not using EntityManager though. How that has been achieved?

Comment: Huh - well, I would have sworn that this was not possible. I'm personally out of answers here.

Comment: GreyBeardedGeek I have managed to call Oracle function or procedure using EntityManager(Hibernate 4), see my answer. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 1):

JPA 2.1 early draft states that there will be support for stored procedures, [according to Arun Gupta](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/jpa_2_1_early_draft) from Oracle.

> Support for Stored Procedures: Added support for the invocation of predefined database functions and user-defined database functions to the Java Persistence query language.
>
> There are different variants of `EntityManager.createXXXStoredProcedureQuery` methods that return a StoredProcedureQuery for executing a stored procedure.  Just liked `@NamedQuery`, there is `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` that specifies and names a stored procedure, its parameters, and its result type. This annotation can be specified on an entity or mapped superclass. The name specified in the annotation is then used in `EntityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery`. The IN, OUT, and INOUT parameters can be set and used to retrieve values passed back from the procedure. For example:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name="topGiftsStoredProcedure", procedureName="Top10Gifts")
public class Product {
 . . .
}

// In your client

StoredProcedreQuery query = EntityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("topGiftsStoredProcedure");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.INOUT);
query.setParameter(1, "top10");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.setParameter(2, 100);
// there are other setParameter methods for defining the temporal type of a parameter
. . .
query.execute();
String response = query.getOutputParameterValue(1);
```

As for when the spec is going to be finalized, or when Hibernate will support JPA 2.1, I can't say.  But it might be worth keeping an eye out.

Comment: A question, I am using a Oracle function, so can I use `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery`?

Comment: That's what the spec says, but it could change between now and the final version (as of writing Hibernate does not implement JPA 2.1 yet but it seems [like they are working on it](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Draft-6/javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery.java) ).

Comment: prunge I have managed to call Oracle function or procedure using EntityManager(Hibernate 4), see my answer. Thanks any way.

Comment: JPA 2.1 introduced much better support for stored procedures (e.g. more that one output parameter). See [JPA 2.1 Stored Procedures](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#JPA_2.1_StoredProcedureQuery) for further details

Answer (score 1):

The previous solution doesn´t seem to work with eclipselink. I got this running with native queries under JPA with

```
            List result = em.createNativeQuery("select YOURFUNCTION(?) from dual ")
                      .setParameter(1, ONEPARAMETER)
                      .getResultList();
```

Comment: Yes, you are right perhaps, it wouldn't work with EclipseLink. I tried that with Hibernate.

Comment: If you are using Eclipselink, try [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jpa/jpa-sql-stored-procedure-example/), look for `With Multiple Parameters (IN and OUT)`