# How to get Hibernate entityManager.createNamedQuery results

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am using Hibernate 4.0

I have method in my DAO class like the following where method return Entity class `Employees`.
I am calling an Oracle function which returns `sys_refcursor`. How can I return `entityManager.createNamedQuery` in my below method?

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
@Override
     public Employees getEmployeeRecords(String employeeNumber) {

         <??> = entityManager.createNamedQuery("myfunction");
     return <??>;

     }
```

Comment: It seems you are calling a stored procedure from Hibernate, can see the answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335939/how-to-call-oracle-function-or-procedure-using-hibernate-4-entitymanager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335939/how-to-call-oracle-function-or-procedure-using-hibernate-4-entitymanager)

Comment: @Genzer My question is if I am using `Query` as `Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getFunc"); query.getResultList();` How can I cast this to `Employees`? Because my method return type is of `Employees`

Comment: When you declare a `NamedNativeQuery` on your `Employee` entity, specify value of attribute `resultClass = Employee.class`, then when you call `query.getResultList()`, it will return a `List<Employee>` just like `NamedQuery`. Though you have to explicitly cast it.

Comment: @Genzer I have already defined `resultClass = Employees.class`. So now can I cast as `Employees e = (Employees) query.getSingleResult();` ?

Comment: Yes. Notice that you also need to implement the stored procedure to return value(s) which mapped to `Employee` entity.

Comment: @Genzer Thanks it worked. Can you post as an answer, I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: Actually I just gave you the link to the real solution. So please go to the link and upvote the answer instead.

Comment: @Genzer Myself added that answer in the link you have provided. :-)

Comment: Wow, I didn't notice that. LOL!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see i do like this

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.name = :name ");
query.setParameter("name", name);

List<Employee> results = query.getResultList();
return results;
```

here i am returning list of Employee type , if you want to send one object then do like this

```
return results.get(0);
```

Regards

Anshul

Answer (score 2):

You  might be interested in "entityManager.createNativeQuery("SQL Syntax query")
where is can execute SQL syntax query. The return datatype would be "ResultSet".

```
ResultSet result = entityManager.createNativeQuery("Your_SQL_function").getSingleResult();
```

On the other hand, 'entityManager.createNamedQuery("defined-query-name")'
should have its query defined ahead earlier than your code execution (either in persistance config, or class annotation).
example:
on top your class

`@NamedQuery(id="findFirstEmployee" query="from Employees e where id = 1")`

your code should look like:

```
public Employees getEmployeeRecords(String employeeNumber) {

    Emloyee result = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findFirstEmployee").getSingleResult();
 return result;
```

---

References:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php