# How to call Oracle function in Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

I would like to call an Oracle function which checks if the user is valid or not in my Java Bean. The function has the following code:

```
  FUNCTION valid_user1(p_username IN VARCHAR2, p_password IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN BOOLEAN AS
    v_dummy VARCHAR2(1);
  BEGIN
    BEGIN
      SELECT '1'
        INTO v_dummy
        FROM t_user
       WHERE username = UPPER(p_username)
         AND password = get_hash(p_username, p_password);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,
                                'Invalid username/pass!');
    END;
    RETURN TRUE;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
  END;
END;
```

I have never called a function in Hibernate and i don't know how to proceed. I read some articles where it was written that is better to use procedure than functions but i did not understand why. Please give me some guidelines how to execute the function using EntityManager. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335939/how-to-call-oracle-function-or-procedure-using-hibernate-4-entitymanager-or-jp
This may help you.

Comment: Thanks, i found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
 Boolean valid = (Boolean)entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT valid_user1(?1,?2) FROM DUAL")
                          .setParameter(1, userName)
                          .setParameter(2, pwd)
                          .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: WARNING: #{loginBean.login(loginBean.name, loginBean.password)}: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
javax.faces.FacesException: #{loginBean.login(loginBean.name, loginBean.password)}: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: The problem came from that that pure SQL does not recognize a boolean type, although PL/SQL does. I replace Boolean with NUMERIC and it works now, thanks.

Comment: But this answer is not a solution