# Hibernate Function returns ORA-14551

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm trying to call a function that returns a integer in oracle 11g with Hibernate 4.3.11.Final, buuut when i try to call it, it throws this exception:

```
 ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query
```

this is the named query:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "generaFolio",
        query = " { CALL GENERA_FOLIO( :idArea ) } ")
```

and inside the function there's a CURSOR and an UPDATE sentence

the function is as follows:

```
    create or replace FUNCTION GENERA_FOLIO 
        (
        areaorigen number
        ) return number
        as
        v_FOLIO      number;
        resource_busy EXCEPTION;
        timeout_expired EXCEPTION;

        PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(timeout_expired,-30006);
        PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (r

esource_busy, -54);

    cursor c1 is 
      select FOLIO FROM FOLIOS f1
        WHERE  
          folio = (select min(folio) from Folios f2 where f2.IDAREA = areaorigen and vlock='D')
          and f1.idarea = areaorigen 
          and vlock='D'
      for update nowait;

    BEGIN

         -- DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Folio para area :: ' || areaorigen);

         BEGIN
             open c1;
             fetch c1 into v_FOLIO;
             close c1;
         EXCEPTION
                 When no_data_found then
                 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'No Existen datos en Folio-area : ' || areaorigen);
                 When timeout_expired then
                 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20002, 'Tiempo de Espera consumido para area : ' || areaorigen);
                 When resource_busy then
                 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20003, 'Folio bloqueado, para la area : ' || areaorigen);
                 When others then
                 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20004, 'Fallo en el momento de tomar folio, de la sig. area: ' ||
                                          areaorigen ||  ' >> Error number ' || SQLCODE || ' >> ' || SQLERRM);
         end;

         --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Folio a Bloquear :: ' || v_folio);

         UPDATE folios SET vlock = 'A'
         WHERE  IDAREA = areaorigen 
         and folio = v_FOLIO;

        --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Folio a Bloqueado! ');

    return  v_FOLIO;
    end GENERA_FOLIO;
```

the way i execute it is:

```
Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery(queryName);    
setParameters(params, query);
Object uniqueResult = query.uniqueResult();
```

calling another function that return a varchar2 and only has SELECTs inside works just fine,

please help :(

**NOTE 1:**
declaring the query as:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "generaFolio", //
query = " { ? = CALL GENERA_FOLIO( :idArea ) } ") })
```

it throws me this error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters: [] [{ ? = CALL GENERA_FOLIO( :idArea ) }]
```

because, as I understand, you can define parameters by position("?") or by  identifier (":idArea") and I'm just setting one :/

**NOTE 2:**

also tried this:

[How to call Oracle Function or Procedure using Hibernate 4 (EntityManager) or JPA 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335939/how-to-call-oracle-function-or-procedure-using-hibernate-4-entitymanager-or-jp)

like:

```
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "generaFolio", //
    query = " { ? = CALL GENERA_FOLIO( :idArea ) } ", //
    hints = { @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true") }),

    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "generaFolio2", //
    query = "{ call GENERA_FOLIO(?,:idArea) }", //
    hints = { @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true") })
```

but in the:

```
Object uniqueResult = query.getFirstResult();
```

both return a NULL...

Comment: Please edit the question and include the code of your procedure, as that's where the error is. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you performing the `CREATE or REPLACE` each time you attempt to run a named query? Why not define the function up-front and then call the function to retrieve the value?

Comment: It looks like hibernate somehow tries to perform `select GENERA_FOLIO( :idArea ) from dual` internally - because of uniqueResult(), perhaps? Try using `query = " { ? = CALL GENERA_FOLIO( :idArea ) }` and query.getResultList() instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14722588/1375470

Comment: @SeanMickey that is just the function definition on my oracle server, not the way i call it.

Comment: @Timekiller YEES! exactly, that is the error, i think, I try that too buuuuut,  let me edit the question to show you what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid the ORA-14551 error by adding this PRAGMA to the Oracle function:

```
pragma autonomous_transaction;
```

It would be best to solve this problem by modifying Hibernate/Java to call the function in a different context but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: dude! it worked! Had to change the query to "select GENERA_FOLIO(:idArea) from dual" and at the end of the function a COMMIT but it worked! thank you very much!