# Mixed parameter strategies - use just one of named, positional or JPA-ordinal strategy

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa-2.0

I am calling function from Oracle database and facing this Exception:

> org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterRecognitionException: Mixed parameter strategies - use just one of named, positional or JPA-ordinal strategy

This is my **User.java** entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "myschema")
@javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery(name = "getPass", query = "{? call = his.get_abc(:mrno)}", resultClass = User.class, hints = {
    @javax.persistence.QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.callable", value = "true") })
public class User {

@Id
@Column(name = "USERID", nullable = false)
private String userid;

@Column(name = "MRNO")
private String mrno;

private String username;
private String password;
private String fullName;
    // Getters and Setters are written.
}
```

And this is how I am calling this function from my one of Service class.

```
public boolean validateUser(String mrno, String password) {

    String completeMrno = utils.getMedicalRecordNumber(mrno);

    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("his-dev");
    EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();

    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getPass"); // <- this line is raising exception.
    query.setParameter("mrno",completeMrno); 
    List<?> results = query.getResultList();
 }
```

So, what changes are required in order to call Oracle Function which returns a String.

Thanks. Let me know if more information is required.

Comment: Just remove ? and the =. Try call his.get_abc(:mrno)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Now I am getting **java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index** when calling `query.getResultList();`

Comment: Ok this does not work for Oracle. Please see my answer

Comment: Ok, Waiting for your answer.

Comment: Did you find solution for above issue.? I am also facing same issue after upgrading spring and hibernate version

Answer (score 0):

Find below an example how to call the function with JPA:

```
Object result = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT his.get_abc(:mrno) FROM DUAL")
                                      .setParameter("mrno", completeMrno)
                                      .getSingleResult();
String value = new String(result);
```

Comment: **java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String]**

Comment: So you get back a byte[] instead of a String. I've updated the answer

Comment: The String I get back is not same as stored in database.

Comment: What string do you get back?

Comment: It is encoded with some special characters. I have tried simple JDBC code (Without JPA/Hibernate) which calls function and gets correct result in String.