# Error while calling an Oracle PL/SQL function from Spring Boot

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, plsql, spring-data-jpa

I have a `Spring Boot` application that is connected to an `Oracle` DB.
This `DB` has a bunch of stored procedures and functions written in `PL/SQL`.

I am trying to call a very simple `PL/SQL` function that takes a string as input and returns a string as output. But I am getting an exception while calling it.

**Error:**

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CHECK_ACTIVE_APPL'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

2019-03-05 11:14:57.456 ERROR WCD1122021 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults; SQL [PKG_USROUTER.CHECK_ACTIVE_APPL]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CHECK_ACTIVE_APPL'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:205)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1043)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3714)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4755)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1378)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.execute(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.<init>(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.outputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:663)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.execute(ProcedureCallImpl.java:646)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ProcedureExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:332)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.checkActiveAppl(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.demo.service.LinkApplService.checkActiveAppl(LinkApplService.java:47)
    at com.example.demo.controller.LinkApplController.getAllApplLinks(LinkApplController.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**PL/SQL Function:**

```
FUNCTION CHECK_ACTIVE_APPL (appl IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  activeFlag VARCHAR2(1);
  BEGIN
    SELECT appl_actv_cd INTO activeFlag FROM   link_appl WHERE  appl_id=appl;
    RETURN activeFlag;
END CHECK_ACTIVE_APPL;
```

**LinkApplController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/applications")
@Log4j2
public class LinkApplController {

    @Autowired
    private LinkApplService linkApplService;

    @GetMapping
    public String getAllApplLinks(Model model) {
        String activeFlag = linkApplService.checkActiveAppl("TITAN");
        log.debug("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@activeFlag: " + activeFlag);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**LinkApplService.java**

```
@Service
public class LinkApplService {

    @Autowired
    private LinkApplRepository linkApplRepository;

    public String checkActiveAppl(String linkApplId) {
        return linkApplRepository.checkActiveAppl(linkApplId);
    }

}
```

**LinkApplRepository.java**

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface LinkApplRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<LinkAppl, String> {

    @Procedure(name = "checkActiveAppl")
    String checkActiveAppl(@Param("linkApplId") String linkApplId);

}
```

**LinkAppl.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LINK_APPL")
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                name = "checkActiveAppl",
                procedureName = "PKG_USROUTER.CHECK_ACTIVE_APPL",
                parameters = {
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "linkApplId", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "activeFlag", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.OUT)
                }
        )
})
public class LinkAppl {
    private String applId;
    private String applDeTx;
    private String seqNbResetCd;
    private String intfMsgFrmtCd;
    private String sndRcvCd;
    private String applAcptMsgFrmtCd;
    private String applActvCd;
    private String sodEodIn;
    private String linkNotesTx;
    private String lastModByUsrId;
    private Timestamp lastModTs;
    private String sndCnctStsCd;
    private Long maxSeqNb;
    private String batIntfIn;
    private String gfpSrcSiteCd;
    private String rcvRterAckmentIn;
    private String rcvMqCodIn;
    private String fxApplIn;
    private String rcvEodpAckmentIn;
}
```

Comment: Just added the model class above with  `@NamedStoredProcedureQueries` annotation as I missed it earlier.

Comment: On your entity you are declaring two parameters: linkApplId and activeFlag, could you remove activeFlag and test it?

Comment: Ok, let me try..

Comment: Error at server startup: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.String com.example.demo.repository.LinkApplRepository.checkActiveAppl(java.lang.String)! No property checkActiveAppl found for type LinkAppl!`

Comment: You should have something like: @NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                name = "checkActiveAppl",
                procedureName = "PKG_USROUTER.CHECK_ACTIVE_APPL",
                resultClasses = { String.class }, 
                parameters = {
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "linkApplId", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN)
                }
        )
})

Comment: Tried this as well. Same error as above at server startup. Seems like you need to have a `ParameterMode.OUT`

Comment: Added both `resultClasses = {String.class}` and also `@StoredProcedureParameter(name = "activeFlag", type = String.class, mode = ParameterMode.OUT)` but getting exception `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.String`

Comment: One last try, could you try change your function to a procedure that receives the out parameter activeFlag and use it to return the read value. Something like: CREATE PROCEDURE CHECK_ACTIVE_APPL (appl IN VARCHAR2, activeFlag OUT VARCHAR2(1) )
BEGIN
    SELECT appl_actv_cd INTO activeFlag FROM   link_appl WHERE  appl_id=appl;
END CHECK_ACTIVE_APPL;

Comment: I don't have privileges to execute any DDL statements on Oracle DB. So sorry I can't try that.

Comment: If all alternatives fail use this  `"BEGIN :activeFlag := PKG_USROUTER.CHECK_ACTIVE_APPL(:linkApplId); END;"`

Answer (score 1):

Finally, this SO link ([How to call Oracle Function or Procedure using Hibernate (EntityManager) or JPA 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335939/how-to-call-oracle-function-or-procedure-using-hibernate-entitymanager-or-jpa/14722588)) and this article (https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedures-and-functions-from-hibernate/) helped me resolve my issue. Changes I did to get things working.

**LinkAppl.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LINK_APPL")
public class LinkAppl {
    private String applId;
    private String applDeTx;
    private String seqNbResetCd;
    private String intfMsgFrmtCd;
    private String sndRcvCd;
    private String applAcptMsgFrmtCd;
    private String applActvCd;
    private String sodEodIn;
    private String linkNotesTx;
    private String lastModByUsrId;
    private Timestamp lastModTs;
    private String sndCnctStsCd;
    private Long maxSeqNb;
    private String batIntfIn;
    private String gfpSrcSiteCd;
    private String rcvRterAckmentIn;
    private String rcvMqCodIn;
    private String fxApplIn;
    private String rcvEodpAckmentIn;
}
```

**LinkApplService.java**

```
@Service
@Log4j2
public class LinkApplService {

    private static final String CHECK_ACTIVE_APPL_QUERY = "select PKG_USROUTER.CHECK_ACTIVE_APPL(:appl) from DUAL";

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @Autowired
    private LinkApplRepository linkApplRepository;

    public String checkApplicationActive(String applicationId) {
        String activeFlag = (String) em.createNativeQuery(CHECK_ACTIVE_APPL_QUERY)
                .setParameter("appl", applicationId)
                .getSingleResult();
        log.debug("activeFlag: " + activeFlag);
        return activeFlag;
    }

}
```

**LinkApplController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/applications")
@Log4j2
public class LinkApplController {

    @Autowired
    private LinkApplService linkApplService;

    @GetMapping
    public String getAllApplLinks(Model model) {
        String activeFlag = linkApplService.checkApplicationActive("TITAN");
        log.debug("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@activeFlag: " + activeFlag);
        model.addAttribute("activeFlag", activeFlag);    
        return "index";
    }
}
```