# How to get a resultset in java code, from a stored procedure in plsql

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, stored-procedures, plsql

I am using MVC pattern
I have two tables : Employee and Address

say,
Employee is like

```
-------------------
Id  | Name   | DeptId
-------------------
101 | Jake   | 501  
102 | Donald | 502
```

and I have one Department table like

```
-----------------------------
DeptId | Name | Description
-----------------------------
501    | IT   | software assistance  
502    | HR   | Human resources
```

Now since I am using MVC these tables are mapped to classes
like

```
@Table(name="Employee")
Class Employee{
   @Id
   @Column(name="Id")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name="Name")
   private String name;

   @Column(name="DeptId")
   private Long deptId;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="DeptId", referencedColumnName="id", insertable=false,updatable=false)
   private Department dept;

   //getters and setters go here
}
```

and the other class Department (mapped to Department table)

```
@Table(name="Department")
    Class Department{
       @Id
       @Column(name="Id")
       private Long id;

       @Column(name="Name")
       private String name;

       @Column(name="Description")
       private String description;

       //getters and setters go here
    }
```

**notice that Employee class has reference to an object of Department class.
This @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn annotations helps us in automatically retrieving corresponding department object along with an employee object**

Its easy with queries directly in code
but how can this be done if I am to use only procedures or functions in my code
I have tried different methods , but it doesn't seem to help

Sometimes I get error something like
`Cannot return resultset from a stored procedure in oracle 10g`

Can anyone please clarify. Also I have to use JNDI

**Can I get my result from the procedure/function in a way that it returns me `List<Employee>` (not a raw resultset which I myself have to sort out into objects) . It should be possible using hibernate no ?**

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your PLSQL needs to return a [ref cursor](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28765/addfunc.htm#CIHIGFFE).

JPA 2.1 has support for mapping CallableStatement out cursors to Entities.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009418/jpa-and-sys-refcursor-like-out-parameter).

Answer (score -1):

I am writing pseudocode ( Not the working example.) But it should solve your problem.

**Oracle**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getEmployees(deptName varchar(20))
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM Employee where DeptId in ( select DeptId from Department where Name =deptName );

END;
/
```

**Hibernate**

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
    "CALL GetStocks(:getEmployees)")
    .addEntity(Employee.class)
    .setParameter("deptName", "Production");

List result = query.list();
for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++){
    Employee emp = (Employee)result.get(i);
    System.out.println(emp.toString());
}
```

Comment: **Sorry ! I need to select Employees, not departments ! Each employee is mapped to a dept because of deptId column. I want corresponding object of Department in 'dept' field of employee. This is straightforward if using queries in java code, but not so easy in case of procedures I think**

Comment: Modified the pseudo code.  You need to try that out